# Accessing Rest service From Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a simple Xamarin forms client application  which accessing .Net WebApi Service. I tested the endpoint using postman it worked perfectly and returned data, but when I using Xamarin app to get data I'm getting an error

> "Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request"

I  mentioned the method which I'm using to get data from rest service

```
public static async Task<dynamic> getDataFromService(string pQueryString)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(pQueryString);

    dynamic data = null;
    if (response != null)
    {
        string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: What is the **InnerException** / Stacktrace?

Comment: The actual query string could be helpful, too, if at any rate possible.

Comment: http://localhost:53269/GetUsers

Answer (score 2):

When using 'localhost' from within a emulator or on a real device, you are accessing the emulator/device and not the development machine where you are probably running the api service. you need to enter a valid url to access the machine where the api is running.

if you tried running postman in the emulator or on a real device you would likely get the same error.